# How to disable app from playing audio?

Tags: iphone, ios

There is an app on my iPhone, 高德地图, that plays audio at the most annoying times when it is open. I don't want it to ever play audio.

How can I disable its ability to play sound?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151478/discussion-on-question-by-minseong-how-to-disable-app-from-playing-audio); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.